# Checklist in longlistselector cropped when shown in WP8 XAML layout

Tags: xaml, checkbox, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Trying to get to grips with Windows Phone 8 and XAML, I started a simple test project. I have in my pivot view a longlistselector showing data entries in a flat list; when the user wants to remove items from the list, he can tap the "select" application bar button and checkboxes appear at the start of each row in the list. To do this, I handle the tap event of the "select" application bar button and set  the `Itemtemplate` and `ListHeaderTemplate` of the longlistselector to data templates including the required checkbox - I don't know if this is the way to do it, but it made sense to me.

My problem though, is that when the DataTemplate including the checkbox is shown, the checkbox is cropped, as shown here in this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the XAML for the DataTemplate that includes checkboxes:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpensesEditListTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="420">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="48" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox 
                IsChecked="False" 
                Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-4,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                />
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding ExpenseCategory}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Amount,StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}"                    
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding PaymentCategory}" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I have tried explicitly setting the row height and column with, but only if using a particularly large value like "80" I can get the checkbox to appear (with a lot of wasted screen space though), as shown below:

[image]

Explicitly setting the checkbox width and height to something smaller (like 20x20) also results in the checkbox not shown at all. Obviously, I must be missing something fundamental about XAML, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's a matter of setting the "correct" margin values. I ended up pasting my `<Grid></Grid>` code directly on the page and visually editing the grid to align the controls correctly. Here is the resulting XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpensesEditListTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="420">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="64" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox 
            IsChecked="{Binding Ischecked}" 
            Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-8,-18,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked"
            />
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding ExpenseCategory}" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Amount,StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}"                    
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
            Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding PaymentCategory}" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
            Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0, 4, 0, 0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, this is still a mystery to me - how did the `Margin="-8,-18,0,0"` turn up to be the right value to align the checkbox? Why is the explicitly set checkbox size ignored? I guess the are some default values I'm not aware of.